# perl how to use is_running

Tags: multithreading, perl

my program is like:

```
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my @thr;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $ARGV[0]; $i++) {
    $thr[$i] = threads->create(\&Iteration, $i);
}

foreach (@thr) {
    if ($_->is_running()) {
        print "no";
    }
    else{
        $_->join;
    }
}

sub Iteration {
    my $in = shift;
    print "test$in\n";
}
```

But when I run it with $ARGV[0], say 5, the output is

```
test2
test1
test0
test3
test4
Can't locate auto/threads/is_running.al in @INC
```

So, how can I use the is_running() statement to check the status of one of my threads?

Comment: What version of threads are you using? (`perl -Mthreads -le'print $threads::VERSION'`)

Comment: I would write «`for(my $i=0;$i<$ARGV[0];$i++){ $thr[$i] = ... }`» as «`for my $i (0 .. $ARGV[0]-1) { push @thr, ... }`»

Comment: 1.07 it says but nothing more. And does you way of writing different from mine or it's just more perl-like?

Comment: The latest version of [`threads`](https://metacpan.org/module/threads) is 1.86. I'd suggest upgrading.

Comment: You're 79 version behind! `is_running` appears to have been added to 1.34.

Comment: damn, but I'm on the school's cluster. No way I can have the authority to upgrade that. BTW, I've tried to download and install the latest 5.16.1 perl source code, but it turns out to be a version cannot support threads, I don't know why. Probably because of some configuration. I install the way that I searched online, which is "tar -xzf perl-5.16.1.tar.gz;
     cd perl-5.16.1;
     ./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl;
     make;
     make test;
     make install;"

Comment: @lolibility: have you tried App:perlbrew and local::lib? (https://metacpan.org/module/App::perlbrew, https://metacpan.org/module/local::lib), http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=953822 has info on compiling with thread support.

Comment: @lolibilty Threads are not compiled in by default.  Information about compiling with threads is in the `INSTALL` document in the source tree.  Long story short: add `-Dusethreads` to the `Configure` arguments.  Also the [threads module](https://metacpan.org/module/threads) can be updated as a CPAN module without updating Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks right. That message indicates the sub doesn't exist, so I suspect you are using an older version of threads, one that did not have such a method. If so, just upgrade your threads module.

```
cpan threads
```

The following should give you the version you have installed (current is 1.86, `is_running` appears to have been added to 1.34):

```
perl -Mthreads -le'print $threads::VERSION'
```

The following should give you the documentation for the version you have installed:

```
perldoc threads
```

Comment: Yeah, I've checked that, but the perldoc only gives you a collection of statements of threads module. Can you give me another source of how to use threads with real examples, that I can learn better?

Comment: damn, but I'm on the school's cluster. No way I can have the authority to upgrade that. BTW, I've tried to download and install the latest 5.16.1 perl source code, but it turns out to be a version cannot support threads, I don't know why. Probably because of some configuration. I install the way that I searched online, which is "tar -xzf perl-5.16.1.tar.gz; cd perl-5.16.1; ./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl; make; make test; make install;"

Comment: @lolibility, You can install a module into any directory, so you don't know any authority whatsoever. But yeah, [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) is cool. I use it. Wouldn't hurt to have a newer version of Perl; yours is ancient! (You can specify `-Duseithreads` when using `perlbrew` too.)

Answer (score 1):

If you really can't upgrade, you can implement `is_running`-like bookkeeping yourself with a shared table of thread IDs.  Something like:

```
package Untested::Workaround;
#
# my $thr = Untested::Workaround->spawn(\&routine, @args);
# ...
# if (Untested::Workaround->is_running($thr)) ...
#
#
...
our %Running : shared;        # Keys are "running" tids

sub _bookkeeping {
  my ($start_routine, @user_args) = @_;
  my $ret;

  { lock(%Running); $Running{ threads->tid() } = 1; }
  $ret = $code->(@args);
  { lock(%Running); delete $Running{ threads->tid() }; }

  $ret;
}

sub spawn {
  shift; #ignore class
  threads->create(\&_bookkeeping, @_);
}

sub is_running { lock %Running; $Running{ $_[1]->tid() }; }
```

Again the above is untested.  It could be improved, either subclassing `threads` or modifying `threads`' namespace to provide a more contemporary, more natural API.  (It also disregards the caller context, something which `threads` preserves for its start routines.)